# solving integral with constant

Tags: integration, constants

I need to solve the following integral:

$\int_{1/4}^{1/2} \frac{C \cos(\pi x)}{\sin^2(\pi x)} \,dx = 1$

I am not sure about how I can solve this regarding the $C$. Should I solve the integral with the substitution method without calculating the integral of $C$? Or is there something else I should do?

Comment: $C$ is not a constant?

Comment: @Bernard you're right, but I was not sure how to call it another way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to derivatives, integrals are "linear operators", which means you can factor constants out of them (and distribute them over sums). In other words,
$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b Cf(x) \,dx &= C \int_a^b f(x) \,dx\\
\int_a^b (f(x) + g(x)) \,dx &= \int_a^b f(x) \,dx + \int_a^b g(x) \,dx
\end{align}$$
All this is to say that you can factor $C$ out of the integral then proceed as normal.

In the particular case of the equation you've given, it looks like $C$ plays the role of normalizing the value of the integral to $1$.